# Generating a dynamic date based on a row number using pentaho pdi

Tags: excel, pentaho, kettle

I want to generate a date dynamically based on row numbers using `pentaho pdi`.
for example:

```
row 1 =====>Date=2015-06-08 **01**:56:30
row 2 =====>Date=2015-06-08 **02**:56:30
row 3 =====>Date=2015-06-08 **03**:56:30
row 4 =====>Date=2015-06-08 **04**:56:30
```

All my data come from an excel spreadsheet with  row number and date fields  and I want the date to change dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily done. Use an `Add sequence` step to generate the row ID. Then the `Calculator` step has a formula called 'Date A + B Hours'. It looks like this:

[image: Add Hours]

I hard coded the base date in the `Generate Rows` step.